# How to use an image with a transparent background?

Tags: css

I don't know how transparency in images work but I do know that png elements have the checker background are supposed to be transparent.

So I thought the checker background would just disappear when I added the image to my div element but it did not. Is there a way to fix this?

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.gameArea {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.game {
    text-align: center;
}

.plane {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(guts.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

-

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
    <h1 class = 'title'>Berserk</h1>


    <div class = "score"></div>
    <div class = "game"> 
        <div class = "gameArea">

            <div class = "plane"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: >>Picture with transparent bg here<<]

Comment: It is because this image is actually not transparent. Try to find other transparent images and I'm sure it will work

Comment: @DavidAlvarez oh :( how do I know if the image is transparent so I can download it? I thought pngs where by default transparent. I'm pretty ignorant on the subject

Comment: Right click on the image > Show image. If it is really transparent, the squared shoudl disappear

Comment: @DavidAlvarez So I can't right click and save-as to download a transparent image? Because on google this and others says they are transparent and they provide a download link. But the download link won't work for me so the only way for me to get the image is to save- as (I use a mac)

Comment: *I do know that png elements have the checker background are supposed to be transparent*, no, it is not, do double check the image in proper image editor such as gimp or photoshop. and see if it had a transparent background (alpha channel). you can make image transparent by yourself, see [Making the background of an image transparent in Gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5454) for clues.

Comment: Got it thanks, I have to get the download link. Save - as won't work. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current picture is a JPG. If it is to be transparent, it must be a PNG. Either you are looking for a new image, or you can edit your current image with GIMP( https://www.gimp.org/ ) and then save as PNG.